# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de un .json en Java?

Tags: java, json

tengo el siguiente archivo .json que representa los distintos datos de varios vinos, es una versión simplificada ya que el archivo contiene otros campos y es mucho mas extenso, pero esto servirá para lo que quiero. Por ahora puedo suponer que el archivo contiene solos estos dos conjuntos.

```
[
 {
 "points": "87",
 "title": "Nicosia 2013 Vulk\u00e0 Bianco  (Etna)",
 "price": null,
 "designation": "Vulk\u00e0 Bianco",
 "variety": "White Blend",
 "province": "Sicily & Sardinia",
 "country": "Italy",
 "winery": "Nicosia"
 },
 {
 "points": "87",
 "title": "Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red (Douro)",
 "price": 15,
 "designation": "Avidagos",
 "variety": "Portuguese Red", 
 "province": "Douro",
 "country": "Portugal",
 "winery": "Quinta dos Avidagos"
 },
 .....
]
```

Quiero acceder a la clave `points` del segundo objeto del Json y mostrar por pantalla su valor "87" pero no tengo idea de como continuar. Intente con esto:

```
public class JSONRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
     try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:\\DANIEL\\winemag-data-130k-v2.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        int points = (int) jsonObject.get("points");
        System.out.println(points);

     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("ERROR. No se encuentra el archivo");
     }
}
```

Y Eclipse me arroja este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.LinkedList.linkFirst(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.addFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:155)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
    at JSONRead.main(JSONRead.java:13)
```

No tengo idea de como continuar.

Estoy utilizando JSON Simple para cargar mi archivo.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda

EDIT: Leyendo el .json me di cuenta de que la mayoría de claves `points` son iguales, así que podría acceder a la clave `price` en su lugar. El problema sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: ¿cuanto pesa el archivo .json?

Comment: El archivo pesa unos 70 Mb, es una colección de vinos, tiene demasiados como para colocarlos aqui, por eso lo reduje a solo dos

Comment: No lo digo para que lo coloques aqui sino porque para mi es un problema de memorio, el error al menos me señala ello: java.lang. **OutOfMemoryError** : Java heap space

Comment: Bueno, en cualquier caso puedo hacer la prueba creando un .json como el que mencione de ejemplo, solo con un par de campos, pues lo que necesito ahora es acceder a las claves. Lo probare

Comment: Exacto, te recomiendo siempre probar ejemplos simples y poco a poco dale complejidad a tus pruebas sino van a saltar un monton de problemas.

Comment: Ahora me sale otro problema, cree otro archivo .json simplifado y compile el codigo, logre ejecutarlo pero ahora me muestra el error del catch. Movi el archivo a varios directorios y nada

Comment: Copia la ruta completa

Comment: Cree un nuevo archivo llamado winery.json y lo copie directamente en la raíz de mi disco. la ruta sería D:\winery.json pero el programa no la detecta, directamente me muestra el mensaje de error que coloque yo. Es decir compila pero muestra el mensaje del "catch"

Comment: Revisa los permisos, te recomiendo usar la carpeta de documentos.

Comment: la ruta no deberia ser: `D:\\winery.json `?

Comment: Ahora no puedo hacer nada, he movido el archivo a multiples carpetas y no lo lee...

Comment: Bueno, tomate un cafe, descansa un poco, y cuando regreses revisa tu codigo parte por parte. :-)

Comment: es que si es ese formato no es un json object si no un json array que contiene mucchos json object

Comment: Estuve leyendo algo de eso tambien pero no me quedo del todo claro como crear un Json Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu Json no es un Objecto es un Array ,puedes recorrerlo así.

public class Prueba {

```
private static final String filePath = "C:\\play\\My.json";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
                    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));
                    JSONArray json = (JSONArray) obj;

                    for (int i = 0; i < json.size(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object =(JSONObject) json.get(i);
                    String clave = object.get("points").toString();  
                    String title = object.get("title").toString();  
                    System.err.println("points:"+clave);
                    System.err.println("title:"+title);

                     }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Error :"+ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esto resolvió mi problema.